# WSO2EMM 2.0.1 unable to register a device (cxf issue?)

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

using the official release of the WSO2 EMM (2.0.1) when trying to enroll an adroid device. When entering a username / password, the server throws the following exception

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-03 14:27:13,652] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/dynamic-client-web] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
        at javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:127)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:110)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:158)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:478)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:196)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
```

When trying to find out what the service call could be, I've got calling the following url:

- https://myserver:9443/dynamic-client-web/register?_wadl

The wso2carbon log claims:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-03 14:35:28,288] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path
[/dynamic-client-web] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.helpers.XMLUtils.xmlEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator.xmlEncodeIfNeeded(WadlGenerator.java:445)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator.getPath(WadlGenerator.java:417)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator.startResourceTag(WadlGenerator.java:394)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator.generateWADL(WadlGenerator.java:282)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator.handleRequest(WadlGenerator.java:241)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RequestPreprocessor.handleMetadataRequest(RequestPreprocessor.java:227)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RequestPreprocessor.checkMetadataRequest(RequestPreprocessor.java:211)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.RequestPreprocessor.preprocess(RequestPreprocessor.java:84)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:108)
```

For me it appears as a wrong version of the CXF used (NoSuchMethodError). Is there any way around?

Comment: This could probably be a known issue in EMM 2.0.1. Follow [EMM-1469](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1469). Please try the latest version and see whether the issue still exists.

Comment: Indeed the 2.1.0 works as intended (at least tested with Android). However - the newest version 2.2.0 uses some internal Android API for the mobile client (e.g. context.startServiceAsUser) and it is unable to build with the default Andoid SDK settings. So - WSO2EMM 2.1.0 so far :) Thank you

Comment: You mean that you are unable to build the Android System Application? Yes, it uses android hidden APIs. You should be able to build the android client without a problem with the default SDK settings. 
[Here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-advanced-handling-of-cope-android-devices-using-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/) is a guide to build the android system application.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part with the custom (unlocked) android.jar :) Now it makes sense and it could work. Thank you :)